# Cyclic electric circuit

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, mathematical-modeling

I have a cyclic electric circuit with N knots and constant resistances $$R_i = 1/N$$.

---

EDIT:

I calculated the incidence matrix B and the conducting matrix C:
$$ B = \matrix{(-1, 1, 0, 0, ..., 0) ; (0, -1, 1, 0, ..., 0) ; (0, 0, -1, 1, 0, ..., 0) ; ... ; (1, 0, ..., 0, -1) }$$
and $$C  = diag(N, ..., N)$$.

In addition, I know that $$ b = (u, 0, 0, ..., 0)^T$$

Now, how does $$(x_1, ..., x_N)$$ look like if the following equation has to be true? 
$$ B^T \times C \times B \times x = B^T \times C \times b$$

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is a cyclic electric circuit with $N$ knots?

Comment: It's like a circle. You have one source of energy, then the first resistance, the second, the third....the N-th. And after the N-th resistance, you are at the end / at the beginning again of the energy source.

Comment: What do you mean by knot?

Comment: Ah this is a point where you can measure the tension.

Comment: Are you sure you are taking about an electrical circuit here? The question is really not clear.

Comment: Well yes...the text of the homework says so.

Comment: @copper.hat I did an edit. I could calculate all the matrices. What still remains is to find a solution for the equation at the end. Can anybody help?